# Capitalize does not work if the text to capitalize is uppercase in ionic3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

In my page i receive a username in uppercase and i want to capitalize.
The problem is that when i apply the `text-transform: capitalize! Important;` it does not work.

On the other hand, if the value i receive is lowercase, if it works.

Any ideas to make a directive that capitalize my uppercase text?

My element:

```
<ion-card-title text-capitalize>{{data.userName}}</ion-card-title>
```

Answer (score 1):

page.html

```
<ion-card-title text-capitalize class="uname">{{data.userName}}</ion-card-title>
```

page.css

```
.uname{
    text-transform: lowercase !important;
}
.uname::first-letter{
    text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```